# Payment getting refunded in inapp billing V4 - Android studio

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

The mail says, "This test purchase was cancelled because it was not acknowledged. You should ensure all purchases are acknowledged so they are not subject to refunds"

Note - for onetime purchase and not subscription

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `acknowledge` purchase programmatically after user purchase your subscription. refer [this document](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#java) and look deep inside `Acknowledge`

[image: Product.Purchases.Acknowledge]